# how to iterate json object in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I have json object and I need to iterate that object in angular. I will tell you my problem. I have one button. On click of that button user can select multiple elements. I take example  ('a','b','c'...so on). When user select **'a'**  and close the pop up I need to show this result.

**Expected result** `when 'a' is selected`

```
A // header 
A S //names
A p
```

When user select 'A' its search from  **showTableData** and show the names below header:

```
"A": [
  { "name":"A S"},
  { "name":"A p"}
  ],
```

When user select 'A' and 'B' then expected result:

```
A                        B // headers

A S                      B BS
A P                      B Bp
```

so on..

Actually I am able to print header if user select any thing  'A' .'B','C'..so on. I don't know how to print it corresponding names below header.

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGNLdR

```
     <div class="row">
       <div ng-repeat="d in data">
  <div class="col" ng-show="d.checked">{{d.name}}</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

is there any other way to take json object to show the expected result ..
can I map different way **data** with **showTabledata** so that i will get expected result ?

```
  $scope.showTableData={
      "A": [
      { "name":"A S"},
      { "name":"A p"}
      ],
      "B": [
      { "name":"B BS"},
      { "name":"B Bp"}
      ],
       "c": [
      { "name":"c c"},
      { "name":"c c"}
      ],
      "d": [
      { "name":"d dS"},
      { "name":"d dp"}
      ],
      "E":[
      { "name":"E ES"},
      { "name":"E Ep"}
      ]
    };
```

Comment: try this A[0].name or A.[0]

Comment: could you use code pen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the simplest solution is just adding another div and iterate in it over your **showTableData** variable, but only by keys which were selected.

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
  <div class="col" ng-show="d.checked">{{d.name}}</div>
     <div class="col" ng-show="d.checked"
        ng-repeat="nameObject in showTableData[d.name]">

            {{nameObject.name}}

     </div>
</div>
```

[Example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNgqjo).

There are some things which can be refactored, but I hope, that you'll get the idea.

---

There is a little bit cleaner solution with using of filter. With this approach you can remove your `ng-show` inside `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data | filter:{checked: true}">
     <div class="col">{{d.name}}</div>
     <div class="col" ng-repeat="nameObject in showTableData[d.name]">

        {{nameObject.name}}

     </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNgjjV).

Comment: It's because of your showTableData variable which contains objects with letters 'A', 'B', but other letters are in small case. I fixed example, try it now. %)

Comment: Thanks for answering what is this meaning "There are some things which can be refactored" .could you please elaborate .could you please give more idea how I will do this

Comment: Yes, sure. I updated my answer. I've meant using ng-repeat and filtering.